# How use spinner with *ngFor async

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, pipe, ngfor

I have one doubt, after the angular v4, we have `pipe async` on `*ngFor` to decrease the code without `subscribe`.
Before that, I always used one variable boolean to show spinner when started request and remove when get response!
Now with `async`, how can I do that without subscribe? What is the best way?
I tried that:

```
  users: Observable<User[]>

  <ion-spinner *ngIf="!users" class="spinner" name="circles"></ion-spinner>
  <ion-list no-lines>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let user of users | async" (click)="onChatCreate(user)">
      {{ user.name }}
    </button>
  </ion-list>
```

But is not working... Any one have an idea to help?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make use of `ngIf..else` as given below

```
<div *ngIf="ovservable$ | async as user; else loading">

</div>
<ng-template #loading>
  Loading...
</ng-template>
```

check here : [`NgIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer, but I didn't understand how to use that with ngFor? Thanks again!

Comment: Got it! It's working! I put that in ion-list, and *ngFor in button right? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Chiien - that will do, please do accept answer if works for you